# Type function return using contextual type rather than from inference

Tags: typescript

With Typescript 2.2.2 (with `strictNullChecks` option true) I was surprised by the following.  Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

```
interface Fn {
    (value: any): number;
}

var example1: Fn = function(value) {
    if (value === -1) {
        return undefined;  // no error, was expecting error
    }
    return value;
};

var example2 = function(value: any): number {
    if (value === -1) {
        return undefined;  // errors correctly
    }
    return value;
};
```

I understand `example1` is not erroring as the function return type is inferred as being `any | undefined`.  `any | undefined` is then compared to the contextual typing of `Fn` return type, i.e. `number` and therefore found to be compatible.  I was instead expecting the return type of the function to **be set by the contextual typing rather than compared to it**.  Is there any way to enforce this other that have the consumer of `Fn` to also explicitly type the function return?

I guess this comes back to interfaces only providing contracts that must be fulfilled rather than dictating implementation including the return type.

Also (out of interest) the error obviously gets caught when the parameter type (`number`) causes the inferred return type (`number | undefined`) to be incompatible with the contextual type (from `Fn2`, i.e. `number`):

```
interface Fn2 {
    (value: number): number;
}

// `example3` errors as function return type is inferred to be `number | undefined` which is incompatible with the expected `number` return type.
var example3: Fn2 = function(value) {
    if (value === -1) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return value;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this is to replace `any` with all available primitives and non primitives:

```
interface Fn {
    (value: number | string | boolean | null | undefined | object): number;
}

// `example1` now errors as expected due to having a return type which is incompatible:
//     Type 'string | number | boolean | object | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
//         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
var example1: Fn = function(value) {
    if (value === -1) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return value;
};
```

[For an excellent explanation of why this works please see FstTesla's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43544372/539490)

Answer (score 1):

The exact inferred type of the function expression you assign to `example1` is `(value: any) => any`, because the return type `any | undefined` is "collapsed" to `any`. Such type is compatible with `Fn` and therefore accepted.

> I guess this comes back to interfaces only providing contracts that must be fulfilled rather than dictating implementation including the return type.

This is not true. On the contrary, type consistency is very strict – that's the purpose of TypeScript after all :) – except of course when `any` is involved, being the most permissive type in the language.

Contextual typing does not apply the type declared on the variable to the function expression. Instead, the types of the `return` statements contribute in determining the type of the function expression. For this reason, I think that there is no way to achieve type safety in the snipped you showed without explicit type annotations on the expression for `example1`.

Please note that the difference between `example1` and `example3` lays in the fact that `any` is special and includes `undefined`, causing the "collapsing" behavior described in the first paragraph.